# tikzmark between = and matrix gives wrong spacing

Tags: spacing, matrices, tikzmark

I would like to be able to access the sides of a `matrix`.

My issue is a that a `tikzmark` placed between a `=` sign and a `matrix` gives wrong spacing.

I get the first output line spacing when I would like the third one. How to fix that ?

### Output

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
  $
  A
  =
  \tikzmark{gauche}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $ the \verb|\tikzmark| is grabbed by \verb|{#1}={#2}| : gives wrong spacing

  $
  A
  =
  {}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $ as if there was a \verb|{}| after the \verb|=|

  $
  A
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $ for reference : what I would like.
\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
  \mathopen{\tikzmark{gauche}}
```

then the spacing is controlled by the tikzmark, an and the second open from the matrix does not add extra space when following the mathopen.

Comment: Thank you. So `\mathopen{\whatever}` has TeX treat `\whatever` as an opening delimiter ; is this right ? It's an analogue to the `\mathbin` command ?

Comment: @marsupilam it's an exact analogue of `\mathbin` (and controls just horizontal space) it doesn't give the other features of delimiters, stretching or `mathinner` from `\left\right`.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing that `tikzmark` should do automatically?  Or are there too many cases to consider?

Answer (score 3):

There is unfortunately no general rule for this.

A `bmatrix` makes an “inner atom”, while `\tikzmark` inserts an empty subformula that counts as an ordinary atom.

By rule, TeX inserts a thin space (more precisely a `\thinmuskip`) between an ordinary and an inner atom. In other cases, when `\tikzmark` sits next to another ordinary atom (a single letter or number, generally), no space is added.

For the special case, you can remove the added space by adding `\!` between `\tizkmark{gauche}` and `\begin{bmatrix}`.

Another strategy is to globally remove the added space with inner atoms (essentially `\left`–`\right` pairs) by using `mleftright`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
  $
  A
  =
  \tikzmark{gauche}\!
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $ the \verb|\tikzmark| now gives right spacing

  $
  A
  =
  {}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $ here there is a \verb|{}| after the \verb|=|

  $
  A
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $ for reference: what I would like.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now with `mleftright` and `\mleftright` in the preamble. Note that, in this case, the spacing is right also with `{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,mleftright}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\mleftright

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
  $
  A
  =
  \tikzmark{gauche}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $ the \verb|\tikzmark| now gives right spacing

  $
  A
  =
  {}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $ here there is a \verb|{}| after the \verb|=|

  $
  A
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $ for reference: what I would like.
\end{document}
```

[image]